# Event Emission Multiple Levels Strategy

Tags: angular, eventemitter

Is there an official convention for passing up data from the bottom most component in a stack of nested components? I'm following the convention of smart parent, stupid child and I'm having trouble deciding between having the grandchild passing it up to parent and the parent passing it up to grandparent vs just using a service. I hesitate to use a service because the components are related and I want to avoid having my services get overly-cluttered with Subjects.

I understand that it's best to keep the folder structure as flat as possible and nesting components should be avoided when possible but in my specific case it makes sense to have it 3 deep.

### Option 1: Grandchild up to grandparent

Service <- Grandparent <- Parent <- Grandchild

**grandchild.component.ts**

```
saveFormValues() {
    this.eventEmitter.emit(this.myForm.value);
}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<app-grandchild (eventEmitter)=relayFormValues($event)></app-grandchild>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
relayFormValues(values) {
    this.relayEvent.emit(values)
}
```

**grandparent.compent.html**

```
<app-parent (relayEvent)=saveChanges($event)></app-parent>
```

**grandparent.component.ts**

```
saveChanges(values) {
    this.myService.save(values).subscribe(() => {...});
}
```

### Option 2

Service <- Grandparent <- Service <- Grandchild

**myservice.service.ts**

```
formSaveEventSource = new Subject<any>;
formSaveEvent$ = this.formSaveEventSource.asObservable();
...
saveFormEvent(values) {
    this.formSaveEventSource.next(values)
}

save(values) {
// http request
}
```

**grandchild.component.ts**

```
saveFormValues() {
    this.myService.saveFormEvent(this.myForm.value);
}
```

**grandparent.component.ts**

```
this.formSaveSub = this.myService.formSaveEvent$.subscribe(data => {
  this.saveChanges(data);
});
...
this.saveChanges(data) {
  this.myService.save(data).subscribe(() => {...})
}
```

I'm leaning towards option 1 with the eventemitter relay because with option 2 we're calling the service twice. Again, just checking to see if there's an official convention or if I'm just overthinking this. The [official docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#component-interaction) only seem to talk about parent and child but no more levels than that.

Comment: Judging by the comments on the [medium blog post](https://netbasal.com/event-emitters-in-angular-13e84ee8d28c) whilst there is disagreement the more experience developers seem to favour avoiding option 1. I'd love to hear other peoples opinions on this but personally, 3 levels is where my answer would be "it depends" and if your components are naturally tightly bound then option 1 seems reasonable.